# Discord.py Bot giving role to user after the have reacted to message

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to create a bot which gives roles, after the user has reacted to a message.

My current code is not working unfortunaly.

```py
async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
    verifiziert = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="verifiziert")
    if str(reaction.emoji) == ":white_check_mark:":
        await user.add_roles(verifiziert)
```

Comment: Maybe use on_raw_reaction_add, because you can check channel and message
Message with role, not with something, eg. meme

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [`on_raw_reaction_add()` Event Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) as opposed to the `on_reaction_add()` Event Reference. This is since the `payload` argument implicitly passed by `discord.py` to `on_raw_reaction_add()` gives more information than the `reaction` and `user` arguments passed by `on_reaction_add()`.

```py
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    role = discord.utils.get(payload.member.guild.roles, name="verifiziert")
    if payload.emoji.name == u"\u2705":
        await payload.member.add_roles(role)
```

*Note that `u"\u2705"` is the unicode equivalent of the **:white_check_mark:** emoji.*